# Trouble getting Fixture Adapter working with Ember App Kit

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having some trouble accessing the store for a DS.FixtureAdapter using Ember App Kit.

My `app/adapters/application.coffee`

```
ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend
`export default ApplicationAdapter`
```

My `models/question.coffee`

```
  Question = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr 'string'
  question: DS.attr 'string'
  date: DS.attr 'date'
  author: DS.attr 'string'

Question.reopenClass
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id:        101,
      title:    'How do I feed hamsters?',
      author:   'Tom Dale',
      date:     '2013-01-01T12:00:00',
      question: 'Tomster cant eat using knife and a fork because his hands are \
                 too small. We are looking for a way to feed him. Any ideas?'
    },
    {
      id:        102,
      title:    'Are humans insane?',
      author:   'Tomster the Hamster',
      date:     '2013-02-02T12:00:00',
      question: 'I mean are totaly nuts? Is there any hope left for them? Should \
                 we hamsters try to save them?'
    }
  ]

`export default Question`
```

My `app/routes/questions/index.coffee`

```
QuestionIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @.store.findAll('question')

`export default QuestionIndexRoute`
```

Now every time I try to load the page it errors out with `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

In Chrome checking the Ember Inspector Data tab, there isn't any data.  Even if I comment out the `@.store.findAll('question')` I still wouldn't see anything.

Been pulling my hair out over this for awhile.  Anybody got any suggestions?

Edit:

Adding in the full stack trace:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at instantiate (http://localhost:8000/vendor/ember/ember.js:11333:26)
    at lookup (http://localhost:8000/vendor/ember/ember.js:11199:19)
    at Object.Container.lookup (http://localhost:8000/vendor/ember/ember.js:10878:16)
    at Ember.Object.extend.adapterFor (http://localhost:8000/vendor/ember-data/ember-data.js:10109:78)
    at Ember.Object.extend.fetchAll (http://localhost:8000/vendor/ember-data/ember-data.js:9417:28)
    at Ember.Object.extend.findAll (http://localhost:8000/vendor/ember-data/ember-data.js:9406:21)
    at Ember.Route.extend.model (http://localhost:8000/assets/app.js:149:27)
    at superWrapper [as model] (http://localhost:8000/vendor/ember/ember.js:1239:16)
    at Ember.Route.Ember.Object.extend.deserialize (http://localhost:8000/vendor/ember/ember.js:35901:19)
    at http://localhost:8000/vendor/ember/ember.js:32521:57
```

Comment: `@.store.findAll('question')` should be `@store.findAll('question')`

Comment: The indentation of your Question model in `question.coffee` also seems off, but that may be from pasting into SO.

Comment: Could you also specify which line is throwing the error?

Comment: @chopper - I tried changed it to `@store.findAll('question') and got the same issue

Comment: Identation is off due to pasting the code.. the coffeescript passes jshint with no issues.  

The line causing the erorr is the `@.store.findAll('question') line.  If I remove that line and just return an array, the page loads fine.

Answer (score 0):

`@.store.findAll('question')` should be `@store.findAll('question')`

Comment: Tried that and it didn't make any difference.  I've edited the original question and added in the stack trace, in case it gives you any ideas.

Comment: Can you try putting in a debugger? In the console, what does `this.store` and `this.store.findAll('question')` return?

Comment: `this.store
Class {typeMaps: Object, recordArrayManager: Class, _relationshipChanges: Object, _pendingSave: Array[0], __ember1395184210171: undefined…}
this.store.findAll('question')
TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: Did you create a store?

Comment: I was under the impression that you didn't need to create the store under Ember App Kit?  `this.store` in the debugger doesn't cause an error and seems to return the correct type

Comment: Hm what if you try just `@store.find('question')`?

Comment: same issue with `@store.find('question')`

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that:

`ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend`

should be

`ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend()`